# Encrypt password on database

Tags: php, sql, encryption, atk4

It's clear for me how to read a user/pass from database using encrypted passwords with SQLAuth, but when I create (for ex.) a register form, how can I do to encrypt the user password ?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$this->api->auth->encryptPassword($password,$salt)`
The first argument is the password string, the second is the salt that is mandatory for sha256/salt encryption mode.

You can store the result in the password field of your model (or in the table directly with dsql).

The first application tutorial can be useful too: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/app/auth

Comment: thats not encryption that's hashing. encyrption involves decryptable keys. keys are not salts.